# microsoft edge css content doesn't work

Tags: html, css

the idea is change the image with another using css, i did this [example](http://codepen.io/alfredoh10/pen/GZvjJa)

```
.hoverCB,.hoverCL,.hoverCC,.hoverCD{
    width:150px !important;
    height:150px !important;
    transition:all 500ms fadeIn;
}
.hoverCB:hover{
        content:url(http://lightingstudio.emin.com.co/wp-content/uploads/icon-bombillo-color.svg);
        transition:all 500ms fadeIn;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue isolated to the MS Edge browser? Why?

Comment: And what exactly does "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The `content` property is only valid on the `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements at this time ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)). Your code shouldn't work on **any** current browser, not just Edge- and any browser that DOES do something (apparently Chromium) has a bug.

If you're trying to do a `background-image` on `:hover`, I suggest you *use the `background-image` property*.

Comment: I checked, it actually works on Chromium. Which does not mean that is is valid, you are right there.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks, well i suppose going to use JS to change the image when the mouse is hover on this one.

Comment: @sittelle Sure, JS in an option, but certainly this can be done in pure css. As said by @abluejelly you just have to take care not to mix things. You can use the `background-image` property which often is more flexible to use than an actual image tag and you can make use of the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. Those can be tied to a `hover` state and you can place them right over the tag they relate to.

Comment: +2 for :: before. backround-image requires you to explicitly set the height and width of the div.